# jquery html doesn't add the entire string

Tags: jquery, html

I found a weird behavior of jquery's html function.

I have the following code snippet.

**HTML**

```
<div id='content'></div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
var test2 = "<h5>test(S)</h5><span class='small_text>Apr 20, 2012 @ 07:00PM<br />Section 102 Row G Seat 14-14<br />";

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#content").html(test2);

});​
```

When I run the code, it can only see 'test(S)'. It looks jquery ignores the rest of the string.

I created a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/E3X33/

Am i using it incorrectly? or is there a undocumented stuff...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not closing the `<span>` tag, plus closing quote of the `class` attribute

Should be:

```
var test2 = "<h5>test(S)</h5><span class='small_text'>Apr 20, 2012 @ 07:00PM<br />Section 102 Row G Seat 14-14<br /></span>";
```

Comment: also the closing single quote in the class attr

Comment: The closing single quote is the bigger of the two problems. Most browsers can handle the non-closed span tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Your jQuery syntax is correct but your HTML is not.

Try this:

```
<h5>test(S)<\/h5><span class='small_text'>Apr 20, 2012 @ 07:00PM<br \/>Section 102 Row G Seat 14-14<br \/><\/span>
```

You needed to:

1. Close your class attribute on the span tag.
2. Close the span tag itself.
3. Escape forward slashes for safety in bad browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try closing your `span` tag and closing `'` for span class:

```
var test2 = "<h5>test(S)</h5><span class='small_text'>Apr 20, 2012 @ 07:00PM<br />Section 102 Row G Seat 14-14<br /></span>";
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/waPVp/)